# Need to show 7 posts from actual date

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, date-query

I have specific category, in what I have a lot of posts.
Every post starts from, for example 21 october 2019.

I have this code to show posts in the correct sequence:

```
class GoroskopController
{

    static function get_data($parent_id, $number, $heading, $heading_color = 'dark')
    {
        $loop = new \WP_Query(GoroskopModule::loop_args($parent_id, $number));

        if ($loop->have_posts()) :

            echo '<div class="goroskop-block mb30">';
            echo '<div class="block-heading-color-small -' . $heading_color . ' font-sans">' . $heading . '</div>';
            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                $this_date = self::this_gor(get_the_title());

                include "templates/block.php";

            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
            echo ($parent_id == 156) ? '<div class="view-more font-sans"><a href="' . get_category_link($parent_id) . '">' . esc_html__('Смотреть все', 'grimple_core') . '</a></div>' : '';
            echo '</div>';

        endif;
    }

    static function now_date()
    {
        $m = [
            'january' => '01',
            'february' => '02',
            'march' => '03',
            'april' => '04',
            'may' => '05',
            'june' => '06',
            'jule' => '07',
            'august' => '08',
            'september' => '09',
            'october' => '10',
            'november' => '11',
            'december' => '12'
        ];

        return $m;
    }

    static function this_gor($title)
    {
        $gor_date = explode(' ', $title);

        $m = self::now_date();
        $this_date = date('d.m.Y');

        $day = (mb_strlen($gor_date[0],'UTF-8') == 1) ? '0' . $gor_date[0] : $gor_date[0];
        $month = $gor_date[1];
        $year = $gor_date[2];

        foreach ($m as $key => $value) {
            if ($month == $key)
                $month = $value;
        }

        $sep = '.';
        $gor_out_date = $day . $sep . $month . $sep . $year;

        $this_gor = ($this_date == $gor_out_date) ? true : '';

        return $this_gor;
    }
}
```

and now I need to show only 7 posts from actual date.

I tried this

```
class GoroskopModule
{

    static function loop_args($parent_id, $number)
    {
        $args = [
            'cat' => $parent_id,
            'showposts' => '7',
            'orderby' => 'ID',
            'order' => 'asc',
            'date_query' => array('after' => date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-2 days')) )
        ];

        return $args;
    }
}
```

but it not work because I have a lot of posts what published in same day.

I need to show 7 posts from actual date calculated in first code. ty

Comment: add in arguments `"posts_per_page" => 7,` [look in the documentation for more details](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Comment: My code shows 7 posts http://prntscr.com/q3osbw , problem it's not from actual date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static function loop_args($parent_id, $number) {
    $today = getdate();
    $args = [
        'cat' => $parent_id,
        'showposts' => '7',
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'year'          => $today["year"],
                'month'         => $today["mon"],
                'day'           => $today["mday"],
            ),
        ),
    ];

    return $args;
}
```